# How to display "compare products" & "recently compared products" sections in a specific category?

Tags: magento

I want to display "compare products" & "recently compared products" sections only in a specific category say electronics.And not everywhere.

How can i achieve this?
Should i change code or only layout and How ?
please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to modifiy the template (phtml files)

you have to work on 
1) product listing (also fro the search) 
2) product details

this is an excpert from list.phtml

```
<ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
```

I will wrap the code that write the "add to compare link" in an if (current category is Electronics) and voilà

regards
Giuseppe